Py4JJavaError while creating SparkSession
I encountered this error while trying to create spark session in a python virtual environment using VS Code as IDE. The code I ran and the output is below, please help.
Code
spark = SparkSession.builder\
            .master("local[1]")\
            .appName("spark-app-version-x")\
            .getOrCreate()````


**Output**

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[3], line 5
      1 # Create SparkSession
      2 spark = SparkSession.builder\
      3             .master("local[1]")\
      4             .appName("spark-app-version-x")\
----> 5             .getOrCreate()

File c:\Users\Oluwa\Documents\DATA PROJECTS\Hands-On Real Time PySpark Project for Beginners\Lab PySpark_1\PSP_1-Venv\Lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\session.py:269, in SparkSession.Builder.getOrCreate(self)
    267     sparkConf.set(key, value)
    268 # This SparkContext may be an existing one.
--> 269 sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(sparkConf)
    270 # Do not update `SparkConf` for existing `SparkContext`, as it's shared
    271 # by all sessions.
    272 session = SparkSession(sc, options=self._options)

File c:\Users\Oluwa\Documents\DATA PROJECTS\Hands-On Real Time PySpark Project for Beginners\Lab PySpark_1\PSP_1-Venv\Lib\site-packages\pyspark\context.py:483, in SparkContext.getOrCreate(cls, conf)
    481 with SparkContext._lock:
    482     if SparkContext._active_spark_context is None:
--> 483         SparkContext(conf=conf or SparkConf())
    484     assert SparkContext._active_spark_context is not None
    485     return SparkContext._active_spark_context

File c:\Users\Oluwa\Documents\DATA PROJECTS\Hands-On Real Time PySpark Project for Beginners\Lab PySpark_1\PSP_1-Venv\Lib\site-packages\pyspark\context.py:197, in SparkContext.__init__(self, master, appName, sparkHome, pyFiles, environment, batchSize, serializer, conf, gateway, jsc, profiler_cls, udf_profiler_cls)
    195 SparkContext._ensure_initialized(self, gateway=gateway, conf=conf)
    196 try:
--> 197     self._do_init(
    198         master,
    199         appName,
    200         sparkHome,
    201         pyFiles,
    202         environment,
    203         batchSize,
    204         serializer,
    205         conf,
    206         jsc,
    207         profiler_cls,
    208         udf_profiler_cls,
    209     )
    210 except BaseException:
    211     # If an error occurs, clean up in order to allow future SparkContext creation:
    212     self.stop()

File c:\Users\Oluwa\Documents\DATA PROJECTS\Hands-On Real Time PySpark Project for Beginners\Lab PySpark_1\PSP_1-Venv\Lib\site-packages\pyspark\context.py:282, in SparkContext._do_init(self, master, appName, sparkHome, pyFiles, environment, batchSize, serializer, conf, jsc, profiler_cls, udf_profiler_cls)
    279 self.environment["PYTHONHASHSEED"] = os.environ.get("PYTHONHASHSEED", "0")
    281 # Create the Java SparkContext through Py4J
--> 282 self._jsc = jsc or self._initialize_context(self._conf._jconf)
    283 # Reset the SparkConf to the one actually used by the SparkContext in JVM.
    284 self._conf = SparkConf(_jconf=self._jsc.sc().conf())

File c:\Users\Oluwa\Documents\DATA PROJECTS\Hands-On Real Time PySpark Project for Beginners\Lab PySpark_1\PSP_1-Venv\Lib\site-packages\pyspark\context.py:402, in SparkContext._initialize_context(self, jconf)
    398 """
    399 Initialize SparkContext in function to allow subclass specific initialization
    400 """
    401 assert self._jvm is not None
--> 402 return self._jvm.JavaSparkContext(jconf)

File c:\Users\Oluwa\Documents\DATA PROJECTS\Hands-On Real Time PySpark Project for Beginners\Lab PySpark_1\PSP_1-Venv\Lib\site-packages\py4j\java_gateway.py:1585, in JavaClass.__call__(self, *args)
   1579 command = proto.CONSTRUCTOR_COMMAND_NAME +\
   1580     self._command_header +\
   1581     args_command +\
   1582     proto.END_COMMAND_PART
   1584 answer = self._gateway_client.send_command(command)
-> 1585 return_value = get_return_value(
   1586     answer, self._gateway_client, None, self._fqn)
   1588 for temp_arg in temp_args:
   1589     temp_arg._detach()

File c:\Users\Oluwa\Documents\DATA PROJECTS\Hands-On Real Time PySpark Project for Beginners\Lab PySpark_1\PSP_1-Venv\Lib\site-packages\py4j\protocol.py:326, in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    324 value = OUTPUT_CONVERTER[type](answer[2:], gateway_client)
    325 if answer[1] == REFERENCE_TYPE:
--> 326     raise Py4JJavaError(
    327         "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
    328         format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    329 else:
    330     raise Py4JError(
    331         "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}. Trace:\n{3}\n".
    332         format(target_id, ".", name, value))

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling None.org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.
: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.apache.spark.unsafe.array.ByteArrayMethods.<clinit>(ByteArrayMethods.java:56)
    at org.apache.spark.memory.MemoryManager.defaultPageSizeBytes$lzycompute(MemoryManager.scala:264)
    at org.apache.spark.memory.MemoryManager.defaultPageSizeBytes(MemoryManager.scala:254)
    at org.apache.spark.memory.MemoryManager.$anonfun$pageSizeBytes$1(MemoryManager.scala:273)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcJ$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcJ$sp.java:23)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
    at org.apache.spark.memory.MemoryManager.<init>(MemoryManager.scala:273)
    at org.apache.spark.memory.UnifiedMemoryManager.<init>(UnifiedMemoryManager.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.memory.UnifiedMemoryManager$.apply(UnifiedMemoryManager.scala:207)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.create(SparkEnv.scala:320)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.createDriverEnv(SparkEnv.scala:194)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.createSparkEnv(SparkContext.scala:279)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:464)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<init>(JavaSparkContext.scala:58)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.newInstance(DirectConstructorHandleAccessor.java:62)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:502)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:486)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:247)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:238)
    at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.invokeConstructor(ConstructorCommand.java:80)
    at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.execute(ConstructorCommand.java:69)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1570)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: java.nio.DirectByteBuffer.<init>(long,int)
    at org.apache.spark.unsafe.Platform.<clinit>(Platform.java:113)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: java.nio.DirectByteBuffer.<init>(long,int)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3784)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2955)
    at org.apache.spark.unsafe.Platform.<clinit>(Platform.java:71)
    ... 25 more



